# Use Placeholder Image if the item.image is null (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using FlatList to render multiple Images on the Screen. I want to render placeholder Image when item.img is null (items are fetched from react-redux).

Problems:

1. I want to use placeholder image using 'require'. And it's using single curly brace. `<Image source={ require('../assets/images/robot-prod.png') } style={styles.palceholderImage}/>`. While normal Image rendering use two curly braces `{{uri: item.img}}`.
2. Should I inline `if(item.img)` operator?

Here is _renderItem function.

```
 _renderItem = ({item}) => {
    let imgUrl = item.img;

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => this._handleCategoryPress(item.id)}>
        <Image
          key={item.id}
          source={{uri: item.img}}
          style={styles.rowImage}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
```

This is API response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Gym",
        "image": "www.aws.blahblahblah"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "School",
        "image": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "hollymo",
        "image": "www.aws.blahblahblah"
    },
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Redux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a full React component. An easy way of controlling rendering based on a completed API call is to use it as a promise and `.then` using `this.setState` If you're well versed in promises:

```
apiPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
  apiData = myApiCall()
  resolve(apiData)
}

class StuffToRender extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    loaded: false
  }
}
componentWillMount() {
  apiPromise().then (() => {
    this.setState({loaded: true})
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.loaded ? myContent : myContentWhileLoading}
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

Also, as a side note, the error you received from the other user's solution has nothing to do with the API/loading logic. It's the fact that you tried to return more than 1 html or component element:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      stuff
    </div>
    <div>
      stuff2
    </div>
  ) //two sets of div elements expose
}
```

Here you are render 2 sets of items. This is what 'multiple children' means. But it's an easy fix. Just wrap the items in one single, larger container.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        stuff
      </div>
      <div>
        stuff2
      </div>
    </div>
  ) //everything wrapped into one single div
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, actually this is not what I'm looking for, but I was always curious about how it handles app loading. Thanks.

Comment: um hold on a sec

Comment: I forgot constructor with `this.state.loaded` as `false`. Also, I overlooked the fact that you're using redux... This changes things. wrapping an API call with `dispatch` already implies a promise in redux, so you don't have to manually do it yourself.

Comment: @JohnBaek Wow, so sorry. I used React syntax, not React Native with `View` and `Text`. But I'm sure you know what I mean at this point ;)

Comment: Thanks for the effort

Comment: @JohnBaek I have an npm package (For regular React), and I have a demo page that shows what my sample code does. Please check it out. Are you sure this is not what you're looking for? Because my answer seems highly relevant. It accomplishes the end goal. It just doesn't use the exact method you described. https://andrew1007.github.io/react-on-images-loaded/

Comment: Remember to cancel the API request in `componentWillUnmount` or you could get an error if the component gets unmounted while the request is processing (even if it might not be needed here, it is good practise whenever you use `setState` in a promise callback).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
       item.image &&      
        <Image
          key={item.id}
          source={{uri: item.img}}
          style={styles.rowImage}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />

       !item.image &&      
        <Image
          key={item.id}
          source={require('../assets/images/robot-prod.png')}
          style={styles.palceholderImage}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
```

Comment: awesome..! um.. how come there is no statement such as `if`.?? Can I just do that?

Comment: @WESLEY John's issue would be the issue of waiting for the async API call to finish. A single pass isn't going to work.

Comment: @Andrew Um actually this is exactly what I'm looking for..! And I'm going to post question about `how to deal with the issue of waiting for the async API call to finish`. Could you optimize that code? It doesn't work.

Comment: Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a sinlge React element child.

Comment: I actually did what you asked just now. It's the complete solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can handle it better in react native by following approach.

As, base64 images render in react native out of the box.

So for your case,

1. Get the base64 data for your placeholder image.
2. In your component,

   `const placeholderBase64image = "data:image/png;base64 [yourbase64imagedata]"`
3. Inside View, use it as:

   `<Image source={{ uri: yourImageUri ? yourImageUri : placeholderBase64image }}/>`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<Image source={ item.img ? { uri: item.img } : require('../images/dummy.png')} />
```

Answer (score 0):

add place holder image in react native Image. use defaultSource tag

```
<Image source={{ uri: require('../images/dummy.png')}} 
            style={styles.itemImage}
            defaultSource={images.dummy} />
```